# passing variable from flask to javascript [flask]

Tags: javascript, python, variables, flask

hi i am creating a captive portal with python and flask (i am inexperienced). i am trying to pass the primary key id of my table from app.py in my index.html code in order to use the id for cookies. how do i integrate id from app.py to index.html with javascript?
thanks

my code:

```
#funzione per registrare un utente
@app.route('/registrautenti',methods=['POST'])
def registrautenti():
    nome = request.form['nome']
    cognome = request.form['cognome']
    email = request.form['email']
    numtelefono = request.form['numtelefono']            
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO inserimentoutenti(Nome,Cognome,Email,Numero_Telefono) VALUES (?,?,?,?)""",(nome,cognome,email,numtelefono))
    cnxn.commit()
    cursor.execute("""SELECT @@IDENTITY AS ID;""")
    print('Id è:{}'.format(cursor.fetchone()[0]))
    cursor.close()
    cnxn.close()
    return render_template('userHome.html')
```

---

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the UserMixin class from Flask, you might be able to use the current_user object, which has the get_id() function.

E.g: current_user.get_id()

This way you can pass it to your template, put in a hidden element, something like:

Link your javascript to your file and use the JS function document.getElementById('user-id')